# Is there an intuitive and rational way to automatically convert ranges into coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I'm tired of typing and deciphering coordinates of the corners rectangles, and I'm wondering if anyone has found a better way.

A rectangle can simply be described by two lists `x = {x1, y1}` and `y = {x2, y2}`, but the coordinates of the corners quickly becomes the jumble `{{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x2, y2}, {x2, y1}}` (if the coordinates are listed clockwise). It gets worse for cubes and higher dimensions.

I've found one promising approach. This is to create two lists for the points on the different axes, `x = {x1, x1, x2, x2}` and `y = {y1, y2, y2, y1}`, and then combine them with `Transpose@Join[{x},{y}]`. This approach extends to higher dimensions and also works for polygons, but it still requires the manual duplication of values.

One could write a function to do this in a black box, but I wonder if there a way to do elegantly and intuitively convert pairs of ranges into coordinates for rectangles?

Comment: Tangentially related, but you may also want to look at this family of functions like `CoordinateBounds` and `CoordinateBoundingBox`: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RegularAndCoordinateArrays.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative, and to get them in clock wise order, is to use `Outer` product, something like

```
canonicalizePolygon[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := Module[{coord},
   coord = Outer[List, {x1, x2}, {y1, y2}];
   coord[[2]] = Reverse[coord[[2]]];
   Flatten[coord, 1]
   ];
```

Call it as

```
canonicalizePolygon[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]
```

[image]

For a `cubiod`, same thing, find coordinates of corners for the front face rectangle, and then find coordinates of corners for the back face rectangle.

For other shapes, I think it will have to be case by case.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I didn't get the purpose of your question/application…

The function `CanonicalizePolygon` helps to find the 4 points of `Rectangle[{x1,y1},{x2,y2}]`

```
CanonicalizePolygon[Rectangle[ {x1, y1}, {x2, y2} ]][[ 1]] 
(*{{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x2, y1}, {x2, y2}}*)
```

or with assumptions

```
CanonicalizePolygon[Rectangle[ {x1, y1}, {x2, y2} ],Assumptions -> {x2 > x1, y2 > y1  }][[ 1]]   
(*{{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x1, y2}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful function to know.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[x];
n = 2;
Tuples@Array[x, {n, 2}]
```

> {{x[1, 1], x[2, 1]}, {x[1, 1], x[2, 2]}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 1]}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 2]}}

3D:

```
ClearAll[x];
n = 3;
Tuples@Array[x, {n, 2}]
```

> {{x[1, 1], x[2, 1], x[3, 1]}, {x[1, 1], x[2, 1], x[3, 2]}, {x[1, 1], x[2, 2], x[3, 1]}, {x[1, 1], x[2, 2], x[3, 2]}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 1], x[3, 1]}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 1], x[3, 2]}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 2], x[3, 1]}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 2], x[3, 2]}}

or

```
x = {x1, y1};
y = {x2, y2};
z = {x3, y3};
Tuples[{x, y, z}]
```

> {{x1, x2, x3}, {x1, x2, y3}, {x1, y2, x3}, {x1, y2, y3}, {y1, x2, x3}, {y1, x2, y3}, {y1, y2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}}

Comment: Straightforward solution! Perhaps `Transpose` missing?: `Tuples@Transpose[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]`